# Using Integrals to Derive the Taylor Series

Tags: taylor-expansion

An answerer gave a derivation ([Where do the factorials come from in the taylor series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209320/where-do-the-factorials-come-from-in-the-taylor-series)) for the standard form of the taylor polynomial series, copied and pasted below for ease of viewing.

I wanted to learn why the use of integrals is justified and, more importantly, what it accomplishes in the derivation. On what grounds could the answerer use integrals?

---

Start with the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$
     f(x) = f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x f^\prime(y) \mathrm{d} y
$$
and reapply it to $f(y)$:
$$
   f(x) = f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x \left( f^\prime(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^y f^{\prime\prime}(z) \mathrm{d} z  \right) \mathrm{d} y = f(x_0) +f^\prime(x_0) \int_{x_0}^x \mathrm{d} y + \underbrace{\int_{x_0}^x \left( \int_{x_0}^y f^{\prime\prime}(z) \mathrm{d} z\right)\mathrm{d} y}_{\mathcal{R}_2(x)}
$$
Repeated this with $f^{\prime\prime}(z)$:
$$
    f(x) = f(x_0) + f^\prime(x_0) \underbrace{\int_{x_0}^x \mathrm{d} y}_{I_1(x)}  + f^{\prime\prime}(x_0) \underbrace{\int_{x_0}^x \int_{x_0}^y \mathrm{d}z \mathrm{d} y}_{I_2(x)} + \underbrace{\int_{x_0}^x \int_{x_0}^y \int_{x_0}^z f(w) \mathrm{d} w \mathrm{d} z \mathrm{d} y}_{\mathcal{R}_3(x)}
$$
 and keeping going we get:
$$
  f(x) = f(x_0) + f^\prime(x_0) \int_{x_0}^x \mathrm{d} y + \cdots + f^{(k)}(x_0) \underbrace{\int_{x_0}^{x} \int_{x_0}^{y_1} \int_{x_0}^{y_2} \cdots \int_{x_0}^{y_{k-2}} \mathrm{d} y_{k-1} \cdots\mathrm{d} y_3 \mathrm{d} y_2 \mathrm{d} y_1}_{I_k(x)} + \mathcal{R}_{k+1}(x)
$$
The iterated integrals $I_k(x)$ are easy to evaluate. They can be defined recursively
$$
   I_0(x) = 1, \quad I_k(x) = \int_{x_0}^x I_{k-1}(y) \mathrm{d} y
$$
Giving $I_k(x) = \frac{1}{k!} (x-x_0)^k$.

Comment: The assumptions are the same as in the Extended Mean Value Theorem.  If $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$, then ...

Comment: @Dr.MV If we want to integrate the derivative, we need more than differentiable, like absolutely continuous and so on :)

Comment: @user2t1w57 The $(n+1)$ order derivative of $f$ exists on the open interval. And plain continuity guarantees $f^{(n)}$ is integrable.